# How to turn the screen blanking/sleep mode off under CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos7, acpi, power-saving

After a few minutes my freshly installed minimal CentOS installation blanks the screen and disconnects the WiFi. The system wakes back up, when I hit any key. I am under the suspicion that this is related to the setting of the screen blanking and/or sleep mode.

I've found a few hints on the web but most of them revolve around window manager settings (I do not have a window manager installed). One that seems to do something, I already tried:

```
sudo setterm -powersave off -blank 0
```

This command does not yield any output but it doesn't fix the problem either: The system keeps to blank the screen after a while.

The `iwconfig` sleep mode device setting is not available since `NetworkManager` is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it worked but not permanently (the setting is reset at reboot). I added the line

```
setterm -powersave off -blank 0
```

to my `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` file and made it executable. This way the setting is set again at boot time.